# PHP functions iconv(), mb_convert_encoding() can't convert KOI8-R to CP1251

Tags: php, iconv

After exporting data from Cronos database to a TXT-file using Windows application I've got a problem - exported data can't be properly viewed on Linux-server (vieweing on Windows is OK).

Here is a example:

`цНПНД|||пЮИНМ|||сКХЖЮ`

I've tried to convert it using PHP, because I'd need to convert it to a huge SQL-file later.

Charset-decoding services showed me, that this text should be converted to CP1251 from KOI8-R, so I've tried it using iconv() and mb_convert_encoding()

So, let's try this:

`$string = iconv('KOI8-R', 'CP1251', $string);`

Result is:
`Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string`

I've googled //IGNORE and tried again:
`$string = iconv('KOI8-R', 'CP1251//IGNORE', $string);`

Result is:
same string - 
`цНПНД|||пЮИНМ|||сКХЖЮ`

Then it was mb_convert_encoding without "from-encoding" argument:
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'CP1251');

The result is:
`?????|||?????|||?????`

... and with "from encoding":
`цНПНД|||пЮИНМ|||сКХЖЮ`

Then it was mirror-attempts (cp1251 to koi8-r). With iconv() I've got "Detected an illegal character in input string"; mb_convert_encoding gave me something new: 
`зПТПД|||тБКПО|||хМЙГБ`
Trying to convert this to UTF-8 showed a lot of different symbols.

I also wanted to convert this file using Notepad++, but it doesn't allow me to open 2.5GB txt-file :(

I've also tried to use iconv as a binary - same errors.

Everything I need is converting this to a readable russian symbols. The best way is to convert it to a UTF-8 but I don't how to do this

`Linux node03 4.4.0-142-generic #168-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 16 21:00:45 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
`iconv (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu11) 2.23`

````
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies```
````

Comment: I suspect your source string is not KOI8 or contaminated.
Use this function to display your string as a hexadecimal string.
function strToHex2 ($ str) {
     return '\ x'.rtrim (chunk_split (strtoupper (bin2hex ($ str)), 2,' \ x '),' \ x ');
}

Comment: ```\xD1\xE8\xF1\xF2\xE5\xEC\xED\xFB\xE9\x20\xED\xEE\xEC\xE5\xF0\x7C\x7C\x7C...```
and what should I do with this?

Comment: This $string = "\xD1\xE8\xF1\xF2\xE5\xEC\xED\xFB\xE9\x20\xED\xEE\xEC\xE5\xF0\x7C\x7C\x7C"; is just another way of writing your source string without falsifications. With$string = iconv('KOI8-R', 'UTF-8', $string); I get that  "яХЯРЕЛМШИ МНЛЕП|||" as a result. Is this the right text?

Comment: I just copied full string, string in a topic was just a cutted example. No, it still is a wrong text

Comment: It should be something like this: ```Системный номер|||Город|||Район|||Улица|||Дом|||Строение|||```

Comment: This character "|" is ASCII and coded in KOI8 ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI8-R ) as well as UTF-8 as "\ x7C". I see this only 3 times in the string $ string = "\ xD1 \ xE8 \ xF1 \ xF2 \ xE5 \ xEC \ xED \ xFB \ xE9 \ x20 \ xED \ xEE \ xEC \ xE5 \ xF0 \ x7C \ x7C \ x7C"; This string can never produce something like this: Системный номер ||| Город ||| Район ||| Улица ||| Дом ||| Строение |||

Answer (score 0):

To use CP1252 with cyrillic letters is not a good idea. Use UTF-8.

PHP can also process strings with charsets != UTF-8 internally.
Attempting to output these strings on a page with a UTF-8 header will result in an incorrect output.
The hexadecimal notation is a possibility to show such strings on UTF-8 pages or to write in the editor under UTF-8.
The function strToHex2 () provides such a string.

```
//Returns a string with escaped chars in hexadecimal notation
function strToHex2($str) {
   return '\x'.rtrim (chunk_split(strtoupper(bin2hex($str)), 2,'\x'),'\x'); 
}
```

The following lines show that the Iconv performs a conversion from KOI8-R to UTF8 (and vice versa):

```
$cityUTF8 = "Город|||";

//convert to KOI8-R
$cityKOI8 = iconv('UTF-8','KOI8-R',$cityUTF8);
echo "KOI8: ".strToHex2($cityKOI8)."<br>";
//KOI8: \xE7\xCF\xD2\xCF\xC4\x7C\x7C\x7C
//compare with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI8-R

//convert back to UTF-8 from KOI8 for a check
$cityUTF8Back = iconv('KOI8-R','UTF-8',$cityKOI8); 

//check if equal
var_dump($cityUTF8 === $cityUTF8Back);  //bool(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Source encoding wasn't KOI8-R. It was CP1251

I convert file using iconv from CP1251 to UTF-8, it helped.